# Is there a nice way to exchange django objects between 2 servers?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 django servers, with their own database, I want to exchange some specific objects between them over the http protocol.
Actually, I planed to create some views to generate XML output on one side to be imported on the other side. Is there a nicer way ?

Comment: I'd use fixtures for this, that's the best way to import / export data with Django IMO. You can either POST from the "source" server or GET from the destination server. If you POST, make sure you have a way to verify the data is coming from a trusted server :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason this needs to happen through http?

If you just want to read data from one server to be used on the other, you could create a simple API that returns a representation of the object you queried for (in xml/json or whatever other format you wanted).

If there is going to be a decent amount of processing going on, or slow communication, and you don't need it to happen real time (in the request/response cycle), you could look at a message queue. Something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for instance.

If you want both servers to have direct access to both databases, you could try to take advantage of [Django's multiple database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) support.

If it's more of a one-off copy of data, just write a small (non-Django) script to do it.

Comment: I agree with serializing the data and sending it not through HTTP...wouldn't be too bad using Python.

Comment: Well, I will have access only to http and ftp protocols. In some cases, enven only email !

Comment: Are you certain no other ports will be open that you can use? 22 (or whatever the SSH port on the machines has been set to) would be useful for data transfer.